# Grease Pencil: Is there a way to create a centerline instead of an outline when doing 'trace image to grease pencil'?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, grease-pencil

I would like to trace multiple images to grease pencil. The problem is that it always creates an outline. What I need is just the centerline so that I can adjust the overall shape thickness later and make it thinner/thicker. Is that possible somehow?

[image]

Comment: Hello. What's your input image like ?

Comment: Just a black and white image - similar to this:

https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/maze-game-hintergrund-labyrinth-mit-ein-und-ausgang-90251131.jpg